# ¿Cómo tener una imagen de avatar por defecto?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un sistema de registro de usuarios y me gustaría que cuando alguien se registre, la foto de avatar o de usuario tenga una foto por defecto. Utilizo `PHP` y `MySQL`.

Lo que quiero decir es que así como muchos sitios en los que las personas se registran y acceden a su perfil, en la zona donde va la imagen de avatar hay una imagen que viene, por así decirlo, por defecto, la cual es parecida a la que muestro mas abajo.

En un principio me llegó la idea de poner un `background-image` con `CSS`  utilizando una imagen (por defecto) y ya cuando el usuario quiera cambiarla, lo haría dinamicamente con `PHP`.

Y cuando el usuario quiera borrar o eliminar la que haya puesto, entonces el avatar volvería a ser la imagen por defecto.

Aquí una imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Acaso es posible así?

Comment: ¿No crees que deberías detallar algo más de tu aplicación y publicar un [mcve]? Yo esperaría eso de alguien que ya tiene 36 publicaciones

Comment: Sin saber muy bien como tienes montado tu sistema, imagino que tendrás un campo con el nombre de la imagen de la foto que ha subido la gente al registrarse. Si NO suben una imagen (el campo estaría a nulo) solo tendrías que devolver el nombre de una imagen "comodín" (como la que has puesto de ejemplo). Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Respuesta: si el usuario no cargo una imagen, usas la imagen por defecto.

Comment: Puedes simplemente guardar la imagen en alguna carpeta de tu directorio y después en la BD solicitarla con la url y así mismo mostrarla en tu código

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que tendras en la BBDD un campo donde se almacene la ruta a la imagen. Solo tienes que comprobar si ese campo es nulo y en caso de que asi sea usar la ruta por defecto a la imagen basica (esta la puedes tener en algun fichero de propiedades por ejemplo).

```
$imagenUsuario = .... // Aqui obtienes la imagen del usuario de BBDD
if($imagenUsuario == null) {
   $imagenUsuario = $urlImagenBasica // Esta la tienes que obtener anteriormente y guardarla en la variable $urlImagenBasica
}
```

Luego cuando el usuario borre la suya, basta con poner a null el campo de la ruta de la imagen en la BBDD

Comment: En realidad yo tengo todo lo que mencionas mas arriba.Almaceno la ruta de la imagen que sube el usuario.Me podrias decir como cargar la foto por defecto en la variable $urlImagenBasica?

Comment: Simplemente usa un fichero de propiedades y cargalo con [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file). Con ello tendras un array asociativo clave-valor.  Solo tendras que asignar a $urlImagenBasica la propiedad correspondiente que hayas definido en el fichero.    Por ejemplo      $array_ini = parse_ini_file("ejemplo.ini");  $urlImagenBasica = $array_ini['imagen_basica'];

Answer (score 0):

Hola Simplemente en la tabla usuarios creas el campo avatar y en el le pones **personalizado** y allí **`default.jpg`** o como quieras llamar al *avatar* por defecto. Así cada vez que se registre alguien ya tendrá su avatar por defecto.

Después deberías poner algún archivo para que pudiera modificarlo. Sobra decir que dicho archivo lo tienes que tener en alguna carpeta a la que enlaces después.